# Use of fbarcode component with delphi-2010

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2010, barcode

I used the fbarcode 1.27 (Free component with source) to make and print barcodes (Using quick reports) in Delphi6. But now I tried with Delphi 2010 and it does not work.

Someone have a solution?

TIA

Comment: Replace all `char` types with `AnsiChar` and all `string` types with `AnsiString`.

Comment: "It does not work". This question does not work. Imagine if you took your car to a garage and said, "it does not work, what is wrong with it". For the love of god, please learn to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Or post a link where we could download the component

Comment: @opc0de: Download is available [here](http://www.torry.net/vcl/misc/barcodes/fbarcode.zip).. BTW, I agree with Andreas. This component was written before D2009 (Unicode).

Answer (score -2):

I did this: replace the array of `char` with `string` (in 2 places)

```
function TAsBarcode.Code_Codabar:string;
type TCodabar =
  record
    c : char;
    data : string; //array[0..6] of char; 
  end;

function TAsBarcode.Code_39:string;

type TCode39 =
  record
    c : char;
    data : string; //array[0..9] of char;
    chk: shortint;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for or solution. Must useful than some comments!!